# How do I disable drag and drop in Google Chrome/Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, accessibility

This is a totally useless function to me which I never use intentionally. DnD starts a ridiculous animation that takes ages to complete. I inadvertently trigger DnD all the time because my mouse is moving around fractionally when I click stuff.

Comment: Is this on a given site or just when you drag a file into the browser? If the latter, that is a function of the OS and is a default method of file opening for applications across the OS. If the former, that is defined by the site features though you may be able to control some functionality in about:flags. Either way, your question needs more information.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen Chrome have _any_ animation on drag-n-drop?

Comment: You can do this on Mac using `defaults write -g NSDragAndDropTextDelay -int 100` [as a variable in milliseconds] but as you didn't tell us what OS you're on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable it for just Chrome. You would have to disable it for your whole computer.